# Responsive Search Form

Tags: css

I have a Search Form as follows:

```
<form method="get" action="#">
  <input type="search" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

I would like the combination of the two inputs to fill 100% ...

The submit input must have fixed width. So the search input must fill the rest of the space.

I would like the form to be responsive ...

I created an example here: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/jiHko

Can I have some help in solving this?

Thank you,
Miguel

Comment: @AleksG [CodePen](http://codepen.io) is something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere How come I've never seen this before?

Comment: @AleksG It's common lately, another one is [codepad](http://codepad.org).

Comment: @insertusernamehere Yeah, I've heard about/seen codepad, just never came across codepen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly easy to accomplish.

All you need is:

1. make the search input occupy 100% width of the parent by `width: 100%;`
2. make both inputs `inline-block` to have them together, add `white-space: nowrap;` property to the `form` element so the button would not go to the next line. (right now the button will stick out of the form to the distance of its width.)
3. add the `padding` property to the `form` element equal to the width of the button

As a result - you should get [something like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqtxE).

I also added `box-sizing` property so visually the form will occupy 40% as needed and removed the actual white space between the inputs by putting them together on one line. If you have a small gap there. There are [ways to fight it](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) too.