# Input field & submit button won't fit in containing element

Tags: html, css, search, input

I'm trying to make my search bar have a fluid input field width, whilst also having a 'search' button next to it.

It seems that the input field **.search** is way bigger than the containing element called **.navigation-right**, and it causes the button **.search-submit** to be pushed out of the containing div. See images below.

**The Issue:**

[image: The Issue]

**What I'm trying to make it look like:**

[image]

**Here is my code: (for convenience I left out the margin & padding values)**

CSS

```css
.navigation-right {
    width: 282px; min-width: 282px;
    height: 50px;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;

    border: 1px solid #920000;
}

.search {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;

    display: table;
}

.search-input {
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;

    display: table-cell;

    border: 1px solid #920000;
    outline: 0px;
}

.search-submit {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    border: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation-right">

    <form class="search">

        <input class="search-input">

        <button class="search-submit"></button>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: So you're looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/xCp4B/

Comment: hi hope my answer will help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below class

```css
.search-input {
    height: 28px;
    width: 70%;

    display: table-cell;

    border: 1px solid #920000;
    outline: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This wasn't _exactly_ what I was looking for, but it did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific need of using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`? It reminds me of the days when the only way of coding was using tables...

If I may suggest [an alternative way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721840/responsive-search-form/18722294#18722294) of doing the same thing and arguably doing it better :) - the `input` element will occupy 100% of its parent with the button having a fixed width (good for fluid or responsive layouts).

Comment: The tables were used as a sort of hack which I had used on other parts on my website as well. It didn't seem to work on here however. I tried your alternative way, and it did seem to work well at first. But later I found out it gave issues whenever I put a padding on the input element. I might have been doing something wrong though.

Comment: @Swen, yep, the `padding` property is added to the `width` by default unless you include the `box-sizing: border-box;` property :) The same thing was done in the linked question

Answer (score 0):

You have set your search field (.search-input) to have a 100% width, so that will fill its parent. You need to reduce the width to around 250px

Answer (score 0):

```
.search-input {
    height: 28px;
    width: 70%;

    display: table-cell;

    border: 1px solid #920000;
    outline: 0px;
    float:left;
}

.search-submit {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    border: 0;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.search-input {
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
      display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #920000;
    outline: 0px;
    position:relative;
float:left;
}

.search-submit {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;

}
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I have post another answer. I hope this is right now.